# Can a Pattern Brush fill any rectangle in win32?

Tags: c++, winapi, gdi

Ok now suppose I have a Bitmap, called `smile.bmp`.

And then I load the bitmap with a **width of 100px** and a **height of 100px**.

```cpp
HBITMAP hBitmap = (HBITMAP)LoadImage(NULL,
                     L"C:/MyImages/smile.bmp",
                     IMAGE_BITMAP,
                     100 /*Width of Image*/,
                     100 /*Height of Image*/,
                     LR_LOADFROMFILE);
// Loading the Bitmap with a width and height of 100px.
```

And then I create a pattern brush using the Bitmap.

```cpp
HBRUSH hBrush = CreatePatternBrush(hBitmap /*The Bitmap*/);
```

Now if I use `FillRect` using this brush, could I using any `RECT` structure?
For example,

```cpp
RECT rect1 = {0, 0, 200, 200};
FillRect(hdc, &rect1, hBrush);
// Would it stretch the Bitmap or not even bother drawing it?
```

If you can recall I loaded the Bitmap with a width and height of **100px**. But now I am filling a rectangle with a width and height of **200px**.

---

So here is my question, would it even fill the area, *or* would it stretch the pixels to match the area?

Comment: Stop using GDI ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will tile the brush pattern to fill the area.  The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/using-brushes) shows an example.